# How to delete Completed Bulk Delete System Job in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I Searched on google on how to delete Completed bulk delete System job in Dynamics CRM and I found following link. 
 https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/185466 
In this link they are saying to create another bulk delete job to delete one but I don't want to keep any bulk delete job in the system.
Why we can't delete bulk delete from within CRM like bulk import and duplicate detection jobs.

 Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to delete those Bulk Delete jobs from the Advanced Find:

[image]

Comment: You can only bulk delete jobs that are "Completed", if they are "Waiting" or otherwise still active you won't be able to delete them, you have to cancel them first.